# Website access based on ssh keys?

Tags: security, web, ssh, ssh-keys

Is there a way to restrict access to a website based on ssh keys? Exactly the same way ssh works:

- If you have a key, access granted -- no password
- If you don't have a key, access denied

If not, what is the best alternative that would satisfy the above conditions? Would I be better off using htuser? I can't restrict access based on IP addresses because the people accessing the site will most likely not always have the same IP.

Comment: A security certificate?

Comment: Use client SSL certificates. Sorry, I don't know enough to give a detailed answer showing how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, using [Mutual-SSL-Authentication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326574/An-Introduction-to-Mutual-SSL-Authentication) you can secure your website using SSL certificates.

I don't know your environment, but here's a pretty detailed writeup on how to perform [mutual authentication on Tomcat](http://techannotation.wordpress.com/2012/06/22/tomcat-mutual-authentication-over-ssl/).

Comment: Oh cool, this looks like what I need. As per my environment, it's an Ubuntu VPS running the basic LAMP stuff.

Comment: You should be able to find a lot of resources on lamp and mutual ssl. Pretty easy to setup. (http://www.cafesoft.com/products/cams/ps/docs30/admin/ConfiguringApache2ForSSLTLSMutualAuthentication.html)

Comment: That's exactly the link I was reading :) Thanks. I'll accept in 7 minutes.